# How do you solicit testers for an open source project?

Tags: testing, open-source

In order to improve my open source project, I need testers. I have created my project independently, so up to now I have been the sole coder and tester. I have tested the thing to death, but as we all know it is dangerous as a developer to test your own code.  I'm looking for ideas on how I can get some other eyes to exercise it.

---

To clarify, I have released it on sourceforge and posted it on freshmeat, dzone, reddit, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for "testers" or "users"?  There's a world of difference.

A tester uses *his* time and energy to find *your* bugs.  How many people are willing to do that?  At a rough guess, I'd say zero.

A user uses *your* software to solve *his* problems.  He reports bugs to you because he thinks that you might fix them for him.  So you've got to find people with a problem, and convince them that your software will fix it.

One thing you'll need is lots of documentation.  A 1-minute screencast, in-depth API, and everything in between.  You need to persuade someone that, "If I use tox, I will totally **rock**!"

That's your tester.

Answer (score 0):

Release an early version, announce it on [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/), and wait for the world to beat a path to your door?

Comment: Tried that.  Got a fair amount of traffic (I'm monitoring it with Google Analytics), but no feedback.  Must mean its perfect, right?

Comment: Could be. 

In any case, it puts you one up on me. Probably that approach works best when your is aimed at a general audience. For more specific tools/toys you should aim a little better. Mind saying what you're working on?

Comment: It is an MVC web application framework using XSLT and PL/SQL primarily.

Comment: So you're looking at a fairly specialized audience who'll need some time to decide if they like it... Patience may be in order. Best of luck.

Comment: Look to the link on my profile.  I don't want to put it here and get down voted for self promotion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to where the testers are. Find sites where testers go. http://www.stickyminds.com,     local QA groups (like mine) http://redearthqa.blogspot.com/ or local recruiters that have QA people looking for experience.